# ng-model on radiobuttons without repitition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

The angular docs' [recommended approach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) for ng-model on radio buttons is to repeat the ng-model on each input element.

I'd like it to be more DRY, to avoid mistakes.

[UPD] I'd also like to have each input element declared explicitly in the html (i.e. the input elements are repeated in the html, but the ng-model is not). So I'd prefer not to use a solution that generates the input elements in a directive, but a directive that modifies existing input elements is fine.

Is there a way to specify the ng-model only once for a set of radio button inputs?

FWIW, I tried creating a directive (on a div containing the inputs) which added an ng-model attribute to each input element, and while it resulted in the correct DOM, the inputs were not bound to the scope. The directive had priority >0 (ng-model has priority 0).

Comment: Create a plunker or fiddle to recreate the problem.

Comment: No need for a plunker - just look a the example code in the linked angular docs - the repetition is right there: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a directive which takes an attribute's value and applies it to the `ng-model` attribute of its children *before the template is compiled and linked*:

#### Directive

```
directive('radio', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    compile: function(tElem, tAttrs) {
      angular.forEach(tElem.find('input'), function(input){
        angular.element(input).attr('ng-model', tAttrs.model)
      });
    }
  }
})
```

#### View

```
<radio model="someModel.value">
  <input type="radio" value="someValue"> Some label
  <input type="radio" value="someOtherValue"> Some other label
</radio>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cc7EqFWeUwtp3JID9CaY?p=preview)

Comment: thanks. i'd been trying to do that, but i was doing it within the pre-link function. i didnt realize the compile function could do stuff (besides returning the linkers). makes good sense now!

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this, one way is to create a directive with an isolate scope that accepts an array of `label`s to be displayed aligned with the `input[radio]` elements and second is the model for all the `input[radio]` elements. Create a template that handles the iteration of each label together with the `ngModel`(input radio) accepted in the `isolate scope`.

UPDATE: You can update all the `input[radio]` elements in your directive before the directive is linked, compile phase. Use `element.find('input')` to get all input radio elements inside the directive regardless of element levels. Evaluate if they are type radio and add the ngModel and name attributes accordingly.

Please see this UPDATED [PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/bKPaH6S6MocHAhF5iCUP?p=preview) (The Size Model Example)

Comment: Thanks for this - it's useful, but not quite what I'm looking for. Please see updated question. Sorry for not being clearer first time.